# pgfplots: plot an integer-sequence by a functional

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

What is the best way to plot an integer-sequence by a functional term, say `2*m+2`?

I tried

```
\addplot[variable=\m, only marks, red] {m==int(m) ? 2*m+2 : nan};
```

But this does not draw anything.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,
declare function={
a(\m)=(\m==int(\m) ? 2*\m+2 : nan);     },
]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$m$},
ylabel={$a(m)$},
title={$a(m)=2m+2$, only normal curve is showing},
axis lines=middle, % 
axis x line=bottom,  % show 0 at origin
xmin=0, xmax=9.5,
ymin=0, ymax=13,
xlabel style={anchor=north west},
ylabel style={anchor=south east},
%grid=major, 
%%enlarge x limits={abs=1.1, upper},
enlarge y limits={rel=0.1, upper},
]
% Normal curve
\addplot[variable=\m, thin, blue] {2*m+2};
% Does not work:
\addplot[variable=\m, only marks, red] {m==int(m) ? 2*m+2 : nan};
% Does not work:
\addplot[variable=\m, densely dashed, green] {a(\m)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PGFPlots calculate the value of functions in some finite amount of points controlled with `samples` or `samples at`. These points does not necessary include integers, but you can force it with `samples at` like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,
declare function={
a(\m)=2*\m+2;     },
]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$m$},
ylabel={$a(m)$},
title={$a(m)=2m+2$, not only normal curve is showing},
axis lines=middle, % 
axis x line=bottom,  % show 0 at origin
xmin=0, xmax=9.5,
ymin=0, ymax=13,
xlabel style={anchor=north west},
ylabel style={anchor=south east},
%grid=major, 
%%enlarge x limits={abs=1.1, upper},
enlarge y limits={rel=0.1, upper},
]
% Normal curve
\addplot[variable=\m, thin, blue] {2*m+2};
% Works:
\addplot[variable=\m, only marks, red, samples at={0,1,...,7}] {2*m+2 };
% Works:
\addplot[variable=\m, densely dashed, mark=+, green, samples at={0,1,...,7}] {a(\m)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with line and marks]